# Value populated by jQuery is undefined in request body

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm creating a simple express application and I have a form such as below:

```
form(action="/user/add" method="POST")
    input(type="text" id="name" name="name" disabled)
    input(type="email" id="email" name="email")
    input(type="submit" value="submit")
```

The name field needs to be filled in with jQuery and cannot be changed so here is what it looks like (it's in a bootstrap modal).

```
a(href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" data-name= valuefromdb)

$("#modal").on("show.bs.modal", function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
  var name = button.data("name");
  var modal = $(this);

  modal.find(".modal-title").text("Edit person" + name);
  modal.find(".modal-body input#name").val(name);
});
```

This works fine and populates the input with the correct name. However when I try to submit it and get the values in the route, I get undefined for the value of name but the email comes through just fine since it was user populated.

```
router.post("/add", function (req, res, next) {
    let person = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email
    };

    console.log(person);
});
```

Which outputs:

```
{ name: undefined,
  email: 'person@mail.com' }
```

Comment: *"However when I try to submit it"* where? how?

Comment: Does is work if don't set the value with jQuery?

Comment: @KevinB the form's action points it to the route...

Comment: @JoeLissner Yes, if I let the value be manually populated by the user it works but it needs to be a dynamic value that cannot be changed by the user.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy what form? generated html?

Comment: @KevinB the form is the first block of code, written in pug.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code from what i can see, so either the input isn't actually in the form, doesn't have a name, or there's some other unknown happening. Debug until you find a cause. Forms don't just magically forget to send an input value.

Comment: Ah, there we go. `disabled` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled -> *"In the case of form elements, it will not be submitted."*

Comment: Yup, remove `disabled` and change it to `readonly`

Comment: or leave it, and add another hidden input that you also set the value to so that you preserve the form's look.